# SwiftUI: Drag & Drop and Corner Radius

Tags: swiftui

My question related to: [How to achieve transparent background or rounded corners when dragging a UICollectionViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62177637/how-to-achieve-transparent-background-or-rounded-corners-when-dragging-a-uicolle)

But how can I do this with SwiftUI?

Comment: is there a solution for the new .draggable API?

func draggable<T>(() -> T) -> some View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution there: [ContextMenu on a rounded LinearGradient produces sharp edges in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62741902/contextmenu-on-a-rounded-lineargradient-produces-sharp-edges-in-swiftui)

So, when I used `contentShape` with `onDrag` it works.

Comment: Does not work for me. I still see a semi-transparent background in the corners while dragging, even after adding `contentShape` with a `RoundedRectangle`. Could you maybe post your working code?

Answer (score 2):

From iOS 15, you can do this:

```
DraggedView()
    .contentShape([.dragPreview], RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
    .onDrag(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for both iOS 15 and below versions:

```
extension View {
    func roundedDragView(cornerRadius: CGFloat) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            return contentShape(.dragPreview, RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius))
         } else {
            return contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius))
        }
    }
}
```